# Prove that $2^p$ + $3^p$ cannot be a perfect square if p is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $p$ is a prime number then $2^p + 3^p$ is not a perfect square.

I don't understand how to start it.
Should I use contradiction to prove?

Comment: You need to restate the question in the body, you can't just have it as a title.

Comment: Ok... Actually i am new here . I don't really know how to properly use it

Comment: I can see that, and welcome. You will find helpful advice [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Note that there are currently two close votes (it takes 5 to close) on your question for "lack of context". People are pretty strict about this for better or for worse. I recommend looking at the "provide context" answer in that link. There are ways to add context other than showing what you've tried, for instance is this a problem from a class you are taking, or from a math contest or something else?

Comment: No i am just preparing for collage

Comment: What you should do is edit the question to say something to the effect of "I am preparing for coll**e**ge and would like to know the answer to this question"

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice from now on I'll see to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All perfect squares are either $0$ or $1$ mod $4$.

We have that $2^{p}+3^{p}\equiv 2^{p}+(-1)^{p}$.

We also have that $p$ is prime, and therefore odd.

Therefore, we have $2^{p}-1$.

We also know that $2^p$ is always $0$ mod $4$, if $p>1$, which it is, because $2$ is the smallest prime.

So that means we $2^{p}-1 \equiv -1 \equiv 3$.

Referring back to the first line, we have that this is not a perfect square.

---

In the case $p=2$, we have $2^2+3^2=13$, which is not a perfect square.

This is an exception because $2$ is even.